# Does creating a child's account in Windows 8.1 have to be a Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts, microsoft-account

[creating a new account in Windows 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br92K.png)

Simple question, when you create a child's account in Windows 8/8.1, is it a local account or a Microsoft account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's way is a Microsoft Account that creates a Child's account as part of the Microsoft Family Account.  That is how how it works on my machine here.

Here is a list of Family Account characteristics that can help you make your choice.

[Microsoft Family Account](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-10/what-is-a-microsoft-family-account/)

> A Microsoft Family account helps families stay connected while keeping
> children safer on Windows 10 PCs, Android devices running Microsoft
> Launcher, and Xbox One devices.

=====================

You could create a Local Standard account and make sure it stays that way.

To be clear, a standard account you make is not a child's account - it is just a standard account.

You can control hours of Internet operation at your router (probably - it depends on the actual router).